# Flutter Split stripe payment

Tags: flutter, split, stripe-payments, payment

How we can split payment to multivendor using Stripe in flutter. All packages support native payment. I am working on taxi booking app. I wants to transfer 20% of payment to company's account and 80% to driver. But I am unable to find any solution to split payment in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

There likely isn't a pre-built solution for you here that does everything.

While Stripe doesn't have a Flutter library today, there's a community library for Flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe

Separately, Stripe offers a product called Stripe Connect that lets you split funds between yourself and a third-party which meets the requirement you outlined. They have detailed guides for various ways to integrate this and you likely want to look at this one first: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide